# Boost Spirit X3: Collapsing one-element lists

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, ebnf, boost-spirit-x3

Say I have a (simplified) recursive grammar like this:

```
OrExpr    := AndExpr % "or"
AndExpr   := Term % "and"
Term      := ParenExpr | String
ParenExpr := '(' >> OrExpr >> ')'
String    := lexeme['"' >> *(char_ - '"') >> '"']
```

So this works, but the problem is that it will wrap everything in multiple layers of expression. For example, the string `"hello" and ("world" or "planet" or "globe")` would parse as `OrExpr(AndExpr("hello", OrExpr(AndExpr("world"), AndExpr("planet"), AndExpr("globe"))))` (playing fast and loose with the syntax, but hopefully you understand). What I'd like is for the one-element nodes to be collapsed into their parent, so it would end up as `AndExpr("hello", OrExpr("world", "parent", "globe"))`

This can be solved with actions and using a state machine that only constructs the outer object if there's more than one child inside it. But I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this problem without using parser actions?

---

**EDIT:** Almost minimal example

[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed66ba050cefee72)

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace burningmime::setmatch::ast
{
    // an expression node (either an AND or an OR)
    struct Expr;

    // child of an expression -- either another expression, or a terminal
    struct Node : x3::variant<std::string, x3::forward_ast<Expr>>
    {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    // tags for expression type
    enum OPER
    {
        OPER_AND = 1,
        OPER_OR = 2
    };

    // see above
    struct Expr
    {
        OPER op;
        std::vector<Node> children;
    };

    // for debugging purposes; this will print all the expressions
    struct AstPrinter
    {
        void operator()(const Expr& node) const
        {
            std::cout << (node.op == OPER_AND ? "And(" : "Or(");
            bool first = true;
            for(const auto& child : node.children)
            {
                if(!first) std::cout << ", ";
                first = false;
                boost::apply_visitor(*this, child);
            }
            std::cout << ")";
        }

        void operator()(const std::string& node) const
        {
            std::cout << node;
        }
    };
}

 // these need to be at top-level scope
 // basically this adds compile-time type information, so the parser knows where to put various attributes
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(burningmime::setmatch::ast::Expr, op, children)

#define DECLARE_RULE(NAME, TYPE) static const x3::rule<class NAME, TYPE> NAME = #NAME;
#define KEYWORD(X) static const auto kw_##X = x3::no_case[#X];
#define DEFINE_RULE(NAME, GRAMMAR) \
    static const auto NAME##_def = GRAMMAR; \
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(NAME)

namespace burningmime::setmatch::parser
{
    // we need to pre-declare the rules so they can be used recursively
    DECLARE_RULE(Phrase, std::string)
    DECLARE_RULE(Term, ast::Node)
    DECLARE_RULE(AndExpr, ast::Expr)
    DECLARE_RULE(OrExpr, ast::Expr)
    DECLARE_RULE(ParenExpr, ast::Expr)

    // keywords
    KEYWORD(and)
    KEYWORD(or)

    static const auto lparen = x3::lit('(');
    static const auto rparen = x3::lit(')');

    // helper parsers
    static const auto keywords = kw_and | kw_or | lparen | rparen;
    static const auto word = x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - x3::ascii::space - lparen - rparen)];
    static const auto bareWord = word - keywords;
    static const auto quotedString = x3::lexeme[x3::char_('"') >> *(x3::char_ - '"') >> x3::char_('"')];

    DEFINE_RULE(Phrase,     quotedString | bareWord)
    DEFINE_RULE(Term,       ParenExpr | Phrase)
    DEFINE_RULE(ParenExpr,  lparen >> OrExpr >> rparen)
    DEFINE_RULE(AndExpr,    x3::attr(ast::OPER_AND) >> (Term % kw_and))
    DEFINE_RULE(OrExpr,     x3::attr(ast::OPER_OR) >> (AndExpr % kw_or))
}

namespace burningmime::setmatch
{
    void parseRuleFluent(const char* buf)
    {
        ast::Expr root;
        auto start = buf, end = start + strlen(buf);
        bool success = x3::phrase_parse(start, end, parser::OrExpr, x3::ascii::space, root);
        if(!success || start != end)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Could not parse rule: ") + buf);
        printf("Result of parsing: %s\n=========================\n", start);
        ast::Node root2(root);
        boost::apply_visitor(ast::AstPrinter(), root2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    burningmime::setmatch::parseRuleFluent(R"#("hello" and ("world" or "planet" or "globe"))#");
}
```

Comment: Hm. I haven't used X3 a lot, but I think the `%` operator is really meant to be used with lists rather than such expressions.

Comment: @Asu edited the example to be clearer. There can be 3 or more elements in a single expression, so it needs to be a list "hello and world and Asu" is a perfectly valid 3-element expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace burningmime::setmatch::ast
{
    // an expression node (either an AND or an OR)
    struct Expr;

    // child of an expression -- either another expression, or a terminal
    struct Node : x3::variant<std::string, x3::forward_ast<Expr>>
    {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    // tags for expression type
    enum OPER
    {
        OPER_AND = 1,
        OPER_OR = 2
    };

    // see above
    struct Expr
    {
        OPER op;
        std::vector<Node> children;
    };

    // for debugging purposes; this will print all the expressions
    struct AstPrinter
    {
        void operator()(const Expr& node) const
        {
            std::cout << (node.op == OPER_AND ? "And(" : "Or(");
            bool first = true;
            for(const auto& child : node.children)
            {
                if(!first) std::cout << ", ";
                first = false;
                boost::apply_visitor(*this, child);
            }
            std::cout << ")";
        }

        void operator()(const std::string& node) const
        {
            std::cout << node;
        }
    };
}

 // these need to be at top-level scope
 // basically this adds compile-time type information, so the parser knows where to put various attributes
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(burningmime::setmatch::ast::Expr, op, children)

#define DECLARE_RULE(NAME, TYPE) static const x3::rule<class NAME##_r, TYPE> NAME = #NAME;
#define KEYWORD(X) static const auto kw_##X = x3::no_case[#X];
#define DEFINE_RULE(NAME, GRAMMAR) \
    static const auto NAME##_def = GRAMMAR; \
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(NAME)

namespace burningmime::setmatch::parser
{
    // we need to pre-declare the rules so they can be used recursively
    DECLARE_RULE(Phrase,    std::string)
    DECLARE_RULE(Term,      ast::Node)
    DECLARE_RULE(AndExpr,   ast::Node)
    DECLARE_RULE(OrExpr,    ast::Node)
    DECLARE_RULE(ParenExpr, ast::Node)

    // keywords
    KEYWORD(and)
    KEYWORD(or)

    static const auto lparen = x3::lit('(');
    static const auto rparen = x3::lit(')');

    // helper parsers
    static const auto keywords = kw_and | kw_or | lparen | rparen;
    static const auto word = x3::lexeme[+(x3::char_ - x3::ascii::space - lparen - rparen)];
    static const auto bareWord = word - keywords;
    static const auto quotedString = x3::lexeme[x3::char_('"') >> *(x3::char_ - '"') >> x3::char_('"')];

    DEFINE_RULE(Phrase,     quotedString | bareWord)
    DEFINE_RULE(Term,       ParenExpr | Phrase)
    DEFINE_RULE(ParenExpr,  lparen >> OrExpr >> rparen)
    template <ast::OPER Op>
    struct make_node
    {
        template <typename Context >
        void operator()(Context const& ctx) const
        {
            if (_attr(ctx).size() == 1)
                _val(ctx) = std::move(_attr(ctx)[0]);
            else
                _val(ctx) = ast::Expr{ Op, std::move(_attr(ctx)) };
        }
    };
    DEFINE_RULE(AndExpr,    (Term % kw_and)[make_node<ast::OPER_AND>{}])
    DEFINE_RULE(OrExpr,     (AndExpr % kw_or)[make_node<ast::OPER_OR>{}])
}

namespace burningmime::setmatch
{
    void parseRuleFluent(const char* buf)
    {
        ast::Node root;
        auto start = buf, end = start + strlen(buf);
        bool success = x3::phrase_parse(start, end, parser::OrExpr, x3::ascii::space, root);
        if (!success || start != end)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Could not parse rule: ") + buf);
        printf("Result of parsing: %s\n=========================\n", start);
        boost::apply_visitor(ast::AstPrinter(), root);
    }
}

int main()
{
    burningmime::setmatch::parseRuleFluent(R"#("hello" and ("world" or "planet" or "globe"))#");
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/kMSHOHG0pgwGr0zv

#### Output:

```
Result of parsing: 
=========================
And("hello", Or("world", "planet", "globe"))
```